# Is it valid to compare 2 strings using type punning?

Tags: c, performance, pointers, optimization

I had just discovered the mindf*** that is type-punning when learning C and while experimenting I ran this code:

```
char* str="abc";
void* n=(void*)str;
uint32_t str_in_int=*(uint32_t*)n;
printf("%u", str_in_int);
```

which obviously gave out a `uint32_t` integer.
Since I thought that this is a pointer operation, if the addresses would be different it would give a different result, but each time I ran it it gave the same result. I also stored a duplicate value in another variable and compared it with the original (in case there were some addressing shenanigans going on under the hood) and it still came out the same. The code:

```
char* str="abc";
char* str2="abc";
void* n=(void*)str;
void* n2=(void*)str2;
uint32_t str_in_int=*(uint32_t*)n;
uint32_t str_in_int2=*(uint32_t*)n2;
printf("%u %u", str_in_int,str_in_int2);
```

Is this a viable form of string comparison in case of smaller strings as an alternative to `strcmp` or comparing character by character? Also an example where the resulting uint is the same for different strings is also welcome if it exists.

Comment: C++ and C are two different languages. They have lots in common, but differ lots in details

Comment: I agree but i think c++ is more like a superset of c. I was under the understanding that both c and c++ would run this code the same, (except the printing part) so i put both c and c++ in there. Thanks for correcting it still.

Comment: @usrnewxnew You should probably change that way of thinking. C++ is not a superset of C, there are many differences.

Comment: @Thomas Jager thanks for the info, I'll keep it in mind

Answer (score 3):

1. It is Undefined Behaviour as you break the string aliasing rules.

The correct way of doing it:

```
    char *str = "abc";
    uint32_t x;

    memcpy(&x, str, sizeof(x));

    printf("%"PRIu32"\n", x);
```

Most optimizing compilers will not call `memcpy` and the performance will be the same as using dangerous pointer punning.

https://godbolt.org/z/fnrn7b9jK

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll use it this way from now. However I'm curious as to why the result of the uint comes the same, by using punning or by using this method.

Comment: Undefined Behaviour means that something might work or not. If you do it using cortex-M0 and your string is not properly aligned it will invoke hardware fault.

Comment: @usrnewxnew: In these particular cases, you have gotten the same results because the `*(uint32_t*)n` nominally says to load data from the address that `n` points to and to interpret that data as a `uint32_t`, and `*(uint32_t)n2` says the same thing for `n2`, and the data that `n` points to is the same as the data that `n2` points to, and the compiler obeyed those instructions in this case, so the same results were obtained. The values of the pointers are irrelevant. The key issue is that the data in the memory is the same.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks a lot for both the answer and this comment, I wish i could upvote it. However is there any case where 2 different strings can be interpreted as the same integer?

Comment: @usrnewxnew no. But yes as well, for example "abcd" and "abcdefgh" using the code above

Comment: @0___________ thanks EDIT: in that case it would just check the first 4 characters i think.

Comment: @usrnewxnew: With `uint32_t` and other exact-width types declared in `<stdint.h>`, any two different sets of bits represent different values. With other types generally, the C standard allows different sets of bits to represent the same value. For example, the type could contain padding bits that are not used as part of the value, so the value would be the same regardless of the padding bits. Or representing negative numbers with sign-and-magnitude could be used, in which case “+0” and “−0” both represent zero. These situations are rare in modern C implementations.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a viable form of string comparison in case of smaller strings as an alternative to strcmp or comparing character by character?

Yes and no. Implementations of `strcmp` and `memcmp` may use techniques like this to compare multiple bytes at once. However, because an implementation of the C standard library is coordinated with the compiler, the code in the library implementation may use things that are not completely defined by the C standard, because they are defined by the compiler. Further, the library will be written to respect alignment requirements and memory mapping issues.

When similar code is written in an ordinary program, the semantics that are not fully defined by the C standard may be changed by the compiler, particularly when high optimization is required. Most particularly, if an object is defined as an array of `char` but you use it as an `uint32_t`, the behavior is not defined by the C standard. Sometimes these issues can be worked around, as the library implementors do, but doing so requires a good knowledge of the C standard and the particular features of the compiler being used.